# AWS Lambda: Enable outbound internet to Lambda functions

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli

I am developing a REST API in `NodeJs` using `AWS Lambda` and `AWS API Gateway`. I am using `AWS SAM` Template as well.

Below is my NodeJS Code. There I am only trying to access a sample API over the internet and make a `POST` call.

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const errorCodes = require('source/error-codes');
const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const prop = PropertiesReader('properties.properties');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: prop.get('server.host'),
    user: prop.get("server.username"),
    password: prop.get("server.password"),
    port: prop.get("server.port"),
    database: prop.get("server.dbname")
});

exports.testApi = async (event, context) => {

    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
    con.config.namedPlaceholders = true;

    if (event.body == null && event.body == undefined) {
        var response = errorCodes.missing_parameters;
        return response;
    }

    let body = JSON.parse(event.body)

    if (body.key == null ) {
        console.log("fire 1");
        var response = errorCodes.not_null_parameters;
        return response;
    }


    try {

        let key = body.key;

        console.log("body", body);

        var notificationMessage = {
            "key": key
        };

        

        const notificationResponse = await fetch("https://reqbin.com/sample/post/json", {
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify(notificationMessage),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        });
        const data = await notificationResponse.json();

        //Return the response
        var response = {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body": JSON.stringify({
                "message": data
            }),
            "isBase64Encoded": false
        }; 

        return response;

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);

        //Return the response
        var response = {
            "statusCode": 500,
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body": JSON.stringify({
                "error": error
            }),
            "isBase64Encoded": false
        }; 

        return response;
    }


};
```

Below is my `template.yaml` file. It contains nested access to another template.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  xxx-restapi

  Sample SAM Template for xxx-restapi
  
# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 5
    VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-xxxxx
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-xxxx
          - subnet-aaaa
          - subnet-bbbb
          - subnet-cccc
          - subnet-dddd
          - subnet-eeee


Parameters:
  FirebaseProjectId:
    Type: String
  
  #Dont create this domain in the AWS Console manually, so it will fail here
  DomainName:
    Type: String
    Default: api2.someapp.com

Resources:

  # Authentication required HTTP API
  AuthGatewayHttpApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      Domain:
        DomainName: !Ref DomainName
        EndpointConfiguration: REGIONAL
        CertificateArn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxxxxx:certificate/bac44716-xxxx-431b-xxxx-xxxx
        Route53:
          HostedZoneId: xxxxxxx
          IpV6: true
      Auth:
        Authorizers:
          FirebaseAuthorizer:
            IdentitySource: $request.header.Authorization
            JwtConfiguration:
              audience:
                - !Ref FirebaseProjectId
              issuer: !Sub https://securetoken.google.com/${FirebaseProjectId}
        DefaultAuthorizer: FirebaseAuthorizer

  # Authentication NOT required HTTP API
  NoAuthGatewayHttpApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      Domain:
        BasePath: noauth
        DomainName: !Ref DomainName
        CertificateArn: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:xxxx:certificate/xxx-420d-xxx-xxx-xxxx
        Route53:
          HostedZoneId: xxxxxx

        
# Lambda settings
  LambdaRole:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::Role'
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - 'sts:AssumeRole'
      Path: /
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: root
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              - Effect: Allow
                Action:
                  - ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces
                  - ec2:CreateNetworkInterface
                  - ec2:DeleteNetworkInterface
                  - ec2:DescribeInstances
                  - ec2:AttachNetworkInterface
                Resource: '*'

Outputs:
  # ServerlessRestApi is an implicit API created out of Events key under Serverless::Function
  # Find out more about other implicit resources you can reference within SAM
  # https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/internals/generated_resources.rst#api
  SharedValueOutput:
    Value: !Ref FirebaseProjectId        
    Description: You can refer to any resource from the template.
  # HelloWorldApi:
  #   Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for Prod stage for functions"
  #   Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/"
```

Below is the nested template file

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  xxx-restapi

  Sample SAM Template for xxx-restapi

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 30
    VpcConfig:
        SecurityGroupIds:
          - sg-xxxx
        SubnetIds:
          - subnet-xxx
          - subnet-aaa
          - subnet-ccc
          - subnet-sss
          - subnet-fff
          - subnet-eee

Parameters:
  FirebaseProjectId:
    Type: String
  
  DomainName:
    Type: String

Resources:

  NoAuthGatewayHttpApi2:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod

  
  MyApiMapping:
    DependsOn: NoAuthGatewayHttpApi2
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::ApiMapping
    Properties:
      ApiMappingKey: no-auth
      DomainName: api2.xxx.com
      ApiId: !Ref NoAuthGatewayHttpApi2
      Stage: !Ref NoAuthGatewayHttpApi2.Stage

  
  
  TestPostFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: xxx-restapi/
      Handler: source/fcm/test-api.testApi
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Events:
        GetRtcTokenAPIEvent:
          Type: HttpApi
          Properties:
            Path: /fcm/test-api
            Method: post
            ApiId: !Ref NoAuthGatewayHttpApi2
```

When I executed the lambda function in local environment it works fine. But if i executed the same after uploading to AWS, it gives me the following error with `503` status code.

```
{
    "message": "Service Unavailable"
}
```

Below is my Cloud Watch log.

```
START RequestId: e84242ea-xxx-4aa0-xxx-xxx Version: $LATEST
2022-06-12T05:55:52.914Z    e84242ea-xxx-4aa0-xxx-xxx   INFO    body { key: 'value' }
END RequestId: e84242ea-xxx-xxx-dd37f2a005c0
REPORT RequestId: e84242ea-xxx-4aa0xxx993e-xxx  Duration: 30032.56 ms   Billed Duration: 30000 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 72 MB  Init Duration: 315.65 ms    
2022-06-12T05:56:22.936Z xxx-b568-xxx-993e-xxx Task timed out after 30.03 seconds
```

After googling I figured out I "may" have not enabled internet connection from my Lambda functions to outside. Even in my API, all Lambda functions that require no Lambda to  outside internet connection is working fine.

I have not configured any VPS, Security group outside the `SAM` Template provided. How can I enable the internet connection to my Lambda function ?

Comment: 'I figured out I may have not enabled internet connection from my Lambda functions to outside' - are you sure this is even the problem? What do the CloudWatch logs say? A 503 error could be *anything*.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary: That is a good question. Please check my updated question. The log says `time out`.

Comment: There we go - your timeout is set to 30s which is apparently too short for whatever you're doing. Go into the general configuration settings for the function and increase the timeout to 2 minutes and retry, please. If it still fails, it's a question of if your application is stuck on something or if your process takes longer. I assume the former but just want to make sure.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary: Well, that is definitely not the case. I tested with 2 minutes anyway, the same result is there. The local execution takes just 2 seconds to execute the post command which a simple command sent to a sample free API

Comment: [How do I give internet access to a Lambda function that's connected to an Amazon VPC?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/)

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary: Thank you but, this is not how it should happen. I am in SAM Template. So it should be done in SAM itself, no manual modifications.